# how to getelementbyid() or getelementbyclassname() from a page that is parsed in google apps script using the urlfetchapp function?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, html-parsing

i want to use google apps script to parse a page and then enter a username and password to input elements on that page. but when i try to use UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText() and then tried to use getelementbyid() to get the desired username and password input fields,nothing happens 
also if somebody could help me with writing a click() command to an element. i have done this with python but i donot know how to automate this using google scripts. please keep the answer specifically in vanilla javascript as i donot understand jquery. i have the xmlservice parsing but it does not work for the url i am interested in

//code.gs

```
function doGet(e){
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('scrapetest');
}

function getUrlData(url) {
var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
return doc                               
}

function getLog(el){

Logger.log(el.length);
}


//scrapetest.html
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
});

//these elements are there is the htmlfile that i created//these can       be fetched using the getElementById() function//

document.getElementById("did").addEventListener("click",fdid);
document.getElementById("dip").addEventListener("click",fdip);

function fdid(){
var url="abc";
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(parsev).getUrlData(url);
}


function parsev(htmlpage){
var el=htmlpage.getElementById('scrollTopBtn');//nothing happens   here and the logger logs nothing
google.script.run.getLog(el);

}
```

Comment: You can't use getElementById() in the context of a text file.  That only works when the DOM is loaded into the Browser ClientSide.  If I'm misunderstanding what you're doing I apologize.

Comment: Can you show the html part of your code containing the elements you try to retrieve?

Comment: hey i am sorry for having replied so late. i had to move to node.js and python to retrieve the web scraped data on my local machine and then update to a google sheet. sorry but this google script scraping seemed to unfamiliar and difficult to me

Comment: @FaisalIshaq: I am asking because it would be helpful to see the part of the code where you define the element `'scrollTopBtn'`